# How can I load some snippets depending on the extension of current file?

Tags: yasnippet, web-mode

When I work on web files I usually use `web-mode` for javascript, php and css files, the problem I have is that yasnippet uses the current mode to find what snippets to load for that buffer ( as stated [in the docs](https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-organization.html) ), but I would like to load a basic set of snippets for the current mode and also load some different sets of snippets depending on the file extension. Is this possible?.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of associating `web-mode` with that extension in `auto-mode-alist`, associate your own custom derivative mode (using `define-derived-mode`), and load whatever you want in the body of that mode.

Comment: See also https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/71322