# Add hooks for a file type based on org-mode

Tags: org-mode, hooks

I have associated a file extension with org mode as follows:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.hy\\'" . org-mode))
```

I have also created certain hooks for org-mode and text mode as follows:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () 
               (visual-line-mode)
               (flyspell-mode -1)
               (column-marker-3 -1)
               (smart-quotes-mode -1)))
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook (lambda () 
                (abbrev-mode)
                (column-marker-3 70)
                (visual-line-mode)
                (flyspell-mode)
                (turn-on-smart-quotes)
                (display-line-numbers-mode)
                (setq-default fill-column 70)))
```

I would like to add hooks now for the specific file type .hy which differ from the default hooks I have for org-mode.

I would like the following modes activated when I work with a .hy file: flyspell-mode, column-marker-mode, auto-fill-mode, line-numbers-mode. I would also like global-visual-line-mode turned off.

I am not sure if this is possible. Would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```el
(define-derived-mode hy-mode org-mode "Hy Mode"
  "Major mode for editing *.hy files."
  do-whatever-you-want-here)

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.hy\\'" . hy-mode))
```

Note that `hy-mode-hook` is automatically defined as well, if you prefer (or need) to use a hook.

Your existing hooks will run as usual, as you now have:

`text-mode` -> `outline-mode` -> `org-mode` -> `hy-mode`

See the heading "Derived modes, and mode hooks" in https://stackoverflow.com/a/19295380/324105 if you wish to understand in more detail how derived modes and mode hooks fit together.  The `do-whatever-you-want-here` above would be the `child-body` in that other answer.

Comment: I have cobbled this together. Welcome any improvements. 

`(define-derived-mode Hy Mode org-mode "Hy Mode"
  "Major mode for editing \\.hy files."
  (text-mode)
  (abbrev-mode)
  (auto-fill-mode)
  (flyspell-mode)
  (column-marker-3 70)
  (display-line-numbers-mode)
  (setq-default fill-column 70))

(add-hook 'hy-mode-hook 'turn-off-smart-quotes)

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.hy\\'" . Hy Mode))`

Comment: Why are you calling `text-mode` in your mode body??  `text-mode` is a major mode -- and one which your `hy-mode` is already a derivative of.  You should derive *directly* from `text-mode` if that's what you really want.

Comment: `setq-default fill-column` is a bug.  You just want `setq` there.

Comment: And although nowadays you don't *need* to do this, I really recommend that when calling a minor mode directly in code, you pass it a positive numeric argument: `(abbrev-mode 1)` rather than `(abbrev-mode)`, and likewise for the others.  The reason is that this provides a distinction between calling major modes and minor modes which wouldn't otherwise exist, which makes the code clearer.

Comment: Oh, you've messed up the syntax.  Please refer to my example.  Your mode should be `hy-mode` derived from `org-mode`, and not `Hy` derived from `Mode` which clearly won't do what you wanted.  I've no idea why you changed that (in both the `define-derived-mode` and the `add-to-list` call), but it's wrong.  Use the format I showed.

Comment: I thought fill-column was a buffer-local variable, which is I used setq-default, not just setq.

Comment: It *is* buffer-local, but the `setq` is running in the buffer in question.  If you use `setq-default` then you're affecting more than just `hy-mode` buffers.

Answer (score 1):

@phils gives you an elegant solution. A cruder one would be to add another function to `org-mode-hook` which tests `(buffer-file-name)` to see whether it ends in `.hy`:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (when (string-match-p "\\.hy\\'" (buffer-file-name))
      (your-code-here))))
```

In your context, I think phils' solution is better.